# Is possible to add keys from different enums to an EnumMap in Java?

Tags: java, enums, enum-map

I have to java enums, A and B, and an EnumMap is it possible to add keys from A and B to this map?

```
EnumMap<? extends Enum,Object> enumMap = new EnumMap(Enum.class);

Object o1 = new Object();
Object o2 = new Object();

Enum e1 = A.X
Enum e2 = B.X
enumMap.put(e1,o1)
enumMap.put(e2,o2)
```

I have tried with no success, is there anything i'm doing wrong?

Comment: What is the error/exception you are getting ?

Comment: How is declared your enumMap ?

Comment: Here is a demo : http://ideone.com/GBysFS ; we need more info, such as an error message to solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Using different enums as keys to the map does not work. From the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/EnumMap.html).

> All of the keys in an enum map must come from a single enum type that is specified, explicitly or implicitly, when the map is created.

You'll need to use a different map implementation.

Answer (score 0):

You can try it in following way. Consider following example.

```
public enum EnumA {
typeA("1");
 EnumA(String s) {
 }

}
```

.

```
public enum EnumB {
typeB("2");

 EnumB(String s) {
}

}
```

Now you can create Map as follows.

```
    Map<Enum,String> enumMap=new HashMap<>();
    enumMap.put(EnumA.typeA,"a");
    enumMap.put(EnumB.typeB, "b");

    System.out.println(enumMap);
```

Answer (score 0):

I justed stumbled upon your question and thought I would like to explain *why* it is not possible to use different enums as keys to the map.

In order to do that, we first have to look into the implementation of EnumMap. In Java, an EnumMap is just an object with an array of the value objects. Let's assume this example:

You have your Enum-class *Colors*:

```
enum Colors { 
    BLUE,
    RED,
    YELLOW;
}
```

and a class that stores some colored fruits in an EnumMap:

```
class MyClass { 
    EnumMap<Colors, String> coloredFruits = new EnumMap<>(Colors.class);

    void main() { 
        coloredFruits.put(Colors.RED, "Apple");
        coloredFruits.put(Colors.BLUE, "Grape");
        coloredFruits.put(Colors.YELLOW, "Banana");
    }
}
```

What Java does now is creating a new EnumMap - object with the following array:

```
String[] values = { "Grape", "Apple", "Banana" }
```

This is exactly what makes an EnumMap so efficient. It's really not more than just an object with an array of value objects and some field that stores the class (in our example that would be `Class keyType = Colors.class` ). In order for this to work as intended there can only be one keyType class.